# single submit button to do three functions

Tags: javascript, php, email

have been a while since i posted last thanks, in advance for all your help in the past..i have a single email box with a submit button.

What i want to do is to check this email address to make sure its not empty, if it is to display a message and then ask user to enter the valid email address which i want to validate so that it is only hotmail and gmail accounts e.g. xyz@hotmail.com and xyz@gmail.com and nothing else..

my code below works ok to check for empty and does display alert message on screen but i do not know how to manpulate the email address check and if all is ok how to use the same one submit button to submit the valid email with thank u popup message after submissions..thanks in advance...singhy

ps: apologises in advance for any beginners mistake i have made ...sorry

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
$to      = 'xyz@hotmail.com';
$subject = '';
$email = $_POST['email_from'];
//$message = "LIST \r\n".
$message = "signoff list name \r\n";

   }

 $email_from = $_POST['email']; 

// create email headers
$message = wordwrap($message, 100, "\r\n");
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>


<p>If you would like to receive our weekly newsletter email address below.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['isgtest'].email_from.value == "")
  {
    alert("Email field is empty, please enter email format");
    return false;
  }
  //return submit "email_from.value";
  (document.forms['test'].email_from.value == "subscribe")
  //return .email_from.value == "";
  //alert("thank u for joining the list !");
  //return true;
}
    </script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<form name="isgtest" class="rform" method="post" action="g.php"> 
<fieldset><legend>testing...</legend> 

<label for="email_from"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>*</strong>
</span>Email address:<input id="email_from" type="text" name="email_from" size="25" />  <input id="insert" id="btn" onclick="return IsEmpty();" style="float: right;" type="button" name="submit" value="Subscribe" /></fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$errors=array(); //track the errors as the script runs
function isValidEmail($addr) // Check for a valid email
{
return filter_var($addr, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

if(!isValidEmail($email_from))$errors[]='Please enter a valid email address';

//Next, test for the email provider you wanted to filter by
$atPos=strpos($email_from,'@');//find the @ symbol
$afterAt=substr($email_from,$atPos,strlen($email_from)-$atPos); //get everything after
$dotPos=strpos($afterAt,'.');
$domain=strtolower(substr($afterAt,0,$dotPos)); //get the typed domain, lowercase
if($domain!='hotmail'||$domain!='gmail')$errors[]='Email must be hotmail or gmail';

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

if(count($errors)<0)
{
$to      = 'xyz@hotmail.com';
$subject = '';
$email = $_POST['email_from'];
//$message = "LIST \r\n".
$message = "signoff list name \r\n";

// create email headers
$message = wordwrap($message, 100, "\r\n");
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
}// note that I changed the nesting to only trigger the mail on post
?>
<p>If you would like to receive our weekly newsletter email address below.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function IsEmpty(){
if(document.forms['isgtest'].email_from.value == "")
{
alert("Email field is empty, please enter email format");
return false;
}
//return submit "email_from.value";
(document.forms['test'].email_from.value == "subscribe")
//return .email_from.value == "";
//alert("thank u for joining the list !");
//return true;
}
</script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript"></script>-->

<?php
if(count($errors)>0)
{
foreach $errors as $e //Now tell the user what went wrong
{
echo "$e<br>"; // you can also use '' to enclose js tags and use alert
}
}
?>

<form name="isgtest" class="rform" method="post" action="g.php"> 
<fieldset><legend>testing...</legend> 

<label for="email_from"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>*</strong>
</span>Email address:<input id="email_from" type="text" name="email_from" size="25" /><input id="insert" id="btn" onclick="return IsEmpty();" style="float: right;" type="button" name="submit" value="Subscribe" />  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: As @Pevara mentioned, never trust user input! Always check for errors on the server side unless it is only for the user's convenience.

Comment: hi andrew thanks for the teak to my code, still trying to get it working , encountering few errors will be in touch , thanks again singhy

Comment: sorry about the late reply, managed to sort the problem as outlined by Andrew Berger, thanks again, singhy :+)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for frontend validation (which should only be used to improve the user experience, never trust user input and always validate at the server side!), why not use the HTML5 features that exist for exactly that purpose. Something like this:

```
<form>
    <label>Email:
        <input type='email' pattern=".+(@gmail.com|@hotmail.com)" required />
    </label>
    <button type="submit">subscribe</button>
</form>
```

- `type=email` makes sure only email addresses are accepted
- `required` makes sure a value is provided before it can be submitted
- `pattern` accepts a regex to which the input needs to comply before it can be submitted.

Personally I'm not a big fan of the default error messages my browser produces, but I'm even less of a fan of the alerts you are using, so...

---

If you insist on going the javascript way, I would advise something like this (pseudo code, untested):

```
function isEmpty(input) { ... }
function isEmail(input) { ... }
function isGmailOrHotmail(input) { ... }
function isValid(node) {
    var value = node.value;
    return ! isEmpty(value) && isEmail(value) && isGmailOrHotmail(value);
}
```

And then you could bind the `isValid` function to your submit button (preferably from your script file or block, but the inline `onclick` way should work as well)

Comment: hi pevara, thanks for the valuable information doing my best to manpulate this into my code...will be in touch if i astray from track, thanks